# Use a variable as a dictionary key in Jinja 2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

```html
<div class = "col-lg-2">
<div class = "shadow card text-center">
{% for i in cart %} 
    {{i}} x {{req["{i}qty"]}}
```

Is there any possible way to pass a `{{req["{i}qty]}}`

And make it behave as if it is `req[f'{i}qty']` in jinja2?

Comment: Where are you getting 'req' from? How is that being passed to Flask?

Comment: Req is coming from session, I passed it through render_template("cart.html", req = sendPage.session)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Have you tried something like this?

{% for i in cart %} 
{{i}} x {{req["{}qty".format(i)]}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @WinmariManzano Glad I could help!